# dynamic keyword example

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm having trouble understanding the dynamic keyword (used .net 2 up til recently).

Can someone please explain what it is for? Perhaps give a simple but real-world example, and explain in what situations in can be used, benefits and drawbacks, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper use of dynamic occurs pretty rarely in practice because you only use it if there is no (convenient) type-safe way of doing the same.

For example:

1. ASP.NET MVC ViewBag (generally inferior to custom ViewModel classes)
2. Access to Javascript objects from C#
3. Some rare cases where you know an object has a certain method but the method is not available statically. Think of database entities which all have an `ID` property by convention

Those are valid use cases but they are not that common.

Comment: 1. Can you give an example? 2. In deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of resolving certain types at runtime.

```
dynamic obj = new A();
obj.method();
```